# Azure Function C# dotnet API Service dependencies issues with System.Diagnositcs.DiagnosticSource

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, azure, mariadb

I am trying to create a Microsoft azure function in VS Code on my Mac, I have tried other OS and machines but this issue has happened with various libraries etc.

The error is this :
For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-02-07T15:02:32.363Z] Executing 'DeletePatient' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=7195c496-2a5d-41f9-bddc-8d4e989a33d7)
[2024-02-07T15:02:32.427Z] Error deleting patient with ID 2: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
[2024-02-07T15:02:32.427Z]
[2024-02-07T15:02:32.443Z] Executed 'DeletePatient' (Succeeded, Id=7195c496-2a5d-41f9-bddc-8d4e989a33d7, Duration=98ms)
[2024-02-07T15:02:34.622Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000EA2C7E34'.

The code of the function I am calling when running the application is:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; // Import the MySqlClient namespace instead of System.Data.SqlClient

namespace PatientDELETE
{
    public static class DeletePatientFunction
    {
        [FunctionName("DeletePatient")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "delete", Route = "patients/{id}")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log,
            int id)
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MySqlConnectionString"); // Update the connection string key as per your configuration

                using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString)) // Use MySqlConnection instead of SqlConnection
                {
                    await conn.OpenAsync();
                    var text = "DELETE FROM Patients WHERE patient_id = @Id"; // Remove "dbo." from table name

                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(text, conn)) // Use MySqlCommand instead of SqlCommand
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);

                        var result = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                        if (result > 0)
                        {
                            return new OkObjectResult(new { Message = $"Patient with ID {id} deleted successfully." }); // Return a message with ID of the deleted patient
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return new NotFoundObjectResult(new { Message = $"Patient with ID {id} not found or could not be deleted." }); // Return a message with ID of the patient not found or not deleted
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError($"Error deleting patient with ID {id}: {ex.Message}");
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the local settings.json file:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "MyMariaDBConnectionString": "Server=DATABASEURL;Port=PORT;Database=DBNAME;Uid=USERNAME;Pwd=PASSWORD;"
  }
}
```

This is the .csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" Version="7.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This is the code of the function it is based off for deleting appointment entries in the database which works perfectly fine.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Patients;

public static class DeleteAppointmentFunction
{
    [FunctionName("DeleteAppointment")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "delete", Route = "appointment/{appointmentId}")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log, int appointmentId)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new PatientDbContext())
            {
                var appointment = await context.Appointments.FindAsync(appointmentId);
                if (appointment == null)
                {
                    return new BadRequestObjectResult(new { Message = $"Appointment with ID {appointmentId} not found or could not be deleted." });
                }

                context.Appointments.Remove(appointment);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return new OkObjectResult(new { Message = $"Appointment with ID {appointmentId} deleted successfully." });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError($"Error while deleting appointment: {ex.Message}");
            return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone might be able to tell me why I am having an issue with System.diagnostics as I havent had an issue with it in the other function and am not sure what to do next.

Comment: Any update on this cos I have exactly the same issue